# Add variable on to its self and other

Tags: javascript, html

is they a way to add a variable onto its self

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = deck;

document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML = deck[0];
document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML = deck[1];
document.getElementById("pc1").innerHTML = deck[2];
document.getElementById("pc2").innerHTML = deck[3];


<p id="demo"></p>

var score = score + deck[0] + deck[1];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = score;


}
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: It is a list of variables

Comment: So how exactly you want to set that list of variable in the `innerHTML` of an element?

Comment: I have the variables getting removed and being used on deck I need them add constantly